# Create DataFrame from multiple Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, series

I have 2 `Series`, given by:

```py
import pandas as pd
r = pd.Series([i*3 for i in range(0, 10)], name='rrr')
s = pd.Series([i*5 for i in range(0, 10)], name='sss')
```

How to I create a `DataFrame` from them?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([r, s], axis=1)
Out: 
   rrr  sss
0    0    0
1    3    5
2    6   10
3    9   15
4   12   20
5   15   25
6   18   30
7   21   35
8   24   40
9   27   45
```

Or the DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame({'r': r, 's': s})

Out: 
    r   s
0   0   0
1   3   5
2   6  10
3   9  15
4  12  20
5  15  25
6  18  30
7  21  35
8  24  40
9  27  45
```

Comment: don't forget you can order the columns in the DataFrame constructor with the `columns` argument https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to the good old DataFrame constructor.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([r, s]).T

# or
df = pd.DataFrame({x.name: x for x in [r, s]})
```

[image: res]