# Using python to input into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, file

I have data in this format:

```
2017-08-01,5.6
2017-09-01,5.6
2017-10-01,5.6
2017-11-01,5.5
2017-12-01,5.5
2018-01-01,5.4
2018-02-01,5.4
```

This data variable was created in this way:

```
data= fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S').to_csv()
```

I have successfully inserted the data into separate columns and rows in a csv file but how could i filter the data variable to say: "only write the rows with a date later than 2010-01-01"? Also how can i define column names, i tried a simple write f.write('col1', 'col2') but this failed?

```
with open("fileName.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

Full code:

```
from fredapi import Fred
import csv
import pandas as pd

fred= Fred(api_key= 'XYZ')
data= fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S').to_csv()

with open("fileName.csv", "w") as f:
    #f.write('hello', 'world')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `data` is a string so, can you share how you built it ? [edit] your post and add more code

Comment: Can you use libraries such as pandas?

Comment: Are we to assume that you are using this API? https://github.com/mortada/fredapi/tree/master/fredapi In which case the `get_series` data returns a Pandas Series object

Answer (score 0):

Use

- [`observation_start`](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi/blob/master/fredapi/fred.py#L109) param to specify the date from which retrieve the data
- use `header` and `index_label` to name the columns for the csv dumping

```
from fredapi import Fred

fred = Fred(api_key=API_KEY)
data = fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', observation_start="2010-01-01")

data.to_csv('filename2.csv', header=['value'], index_label='date')
```

File will be like

```
date,value
2010-01-01,8.0
2010-02-01,8.0
2010-03-01,8.0
```

---

To [join multiple Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941321/create-dataframe-from-multiple-series#answers) use `pandas.concat`

```
data = fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', frequency='m', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data1 = fred.get_series('DEUCPIALLMINMEI', frequency='m', observation_start="2010-01-01")

df = pd.concat([data, data1], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'Germany Unemployment', 1: 'Germany Inflation'})
df.to_csv('german.csv', index_label="date")
```

`DataFrame.fillna` can be useful in case one `Series` have some missing values

```
df.fillna(0).to_csv('german.csv', index_label="date")
```

Giving

```
date,Germany Unemployment,Germany Inflation
2010-01-01,8.0,92.3591431905318
2010-02-01,8.0,92.732311445847
2010-03-01,8.0,93.1987717649912
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be using the "fredapi" the data that they have is already a pandas `Series` object so converting the raw text back to a Dataframe isn't necessary.

Comment: @scotty3785 yep just saw that, I'm editing

Comment: @scotty3785 thanks for all the help. I was wondering, with 2 series from the FRED API how could I  put them both into the same csv file and maintain the ordering based on the associated date, ie the new csv file would have 3 columns, 1 for date(the PK), second the attribute from series1 and third for the attribute in series3.
To be clear: series1 format: date, attribute.
series2 format: date, attribute.

Comment: i currently have the code to retrieve the 2 series but unsure how to merge them on their date:            from fredapi import Fred
import pandas as pd

fred= Fred(api_key= 'API_KEY')
data = fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', frequency = 'm', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data.to_csv('germanU.csv', header=['Germany Unemployment'], index_label='date')

data1 = fred.get_series('DEUCPIALLMINMEI', frequency = 'm', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data1.to_csv('germanInflation.csv', header=['Germany Inflation'], index_label='date')

Comment: @danielstafford Sound like a new question to me. And this isn't my answer, it is from azro.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [fredapi source code](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi/blob/master/fredapi/fred.py#L101), you can specify an `observation_start` parameter to the `get_series` method.

I'd try the following

```
fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', observation_start="2010-01-01").to_csv('filename.csv')
```

This should filter the data to only show observations after the specified date.

To add a header, specify this when you output the csv

```
fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', observation_start="2010-01-01").to_csv('filename.csv', header=['Date','Values'])
```

Comment: i get a ValueError: Writing 1 cols but got 2 aliases when i use your second code insert ie the one with the header=['Date','Values']. Thanks again

Comment: @danielstafford Oops! try `header=['Value'], index_label='Date'` as the arguments instead