# How to create a data frame from two Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame within a while loop from two Panda Series. When I print the two series, I get the following output:
Print(a)
0    0.159175
Name: Time, dtype: float64
0    0.531096
Name: Time, dtype: float64
0    0.688536
Name: Time, dtype: float64
0    0.883937

Print (b)
0    18
Name: Inventory, dtype: int64
0    14
Name: Inventory, dtype: int64
0    12
Name: Inventory, dtype: int64
0    9

I tried to create the data frame with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

while s.clock <= 2.0:
    s.advance_time()
    a = pd.Series([s.clock], name = 'Time')
    b = pd.Series([s.inventory], name = 'Inventory')
    df= pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(a),pd.DataFrame(b)], axis =0, ignore_index=True)
    df
```

df gives this output:

```
        Time  Inventory
0   0.159175        NaN
1        NaN       18.0
2   0.531096        NaN
3        NaN       14.0
4   0.688536        NaN
5        NaN       12.0
6   0.883937        NaN
7        NaN        9.0
8   0.999041        NaN
9        NaN        6.0

How can I get rid of the NAN values from the data frame so that I can have only the values from the series of a and d without NAN? I hope this question makes sense. Thanks.
```

Comment: I would make sure to read the documentation which you can find here. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html
In order to fix your mistake, it looks like you need to change the parameter to axis=1. 
I'm assuming that that the body of the while loop is executed multiple times. Which technically this code would work, you will be getting many columns with duplicate names. It would perhaps do you well to have the series to have different names for each call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create DataFrame from multiple Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941321/create-dataframe-from-multiple-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you will need to split concatenation into two parts: concat `a` and `b` along columns (axis=1), then concat with the existing `df` along rows (axis=0).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()

while s.clock <= 2.0:
    s.advance_time()
    a = pd.Series([s.clock], name = 'Time')
    b = pd.Series([s.inventory], name = 'Inventory')
    _ab = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
    df= pd.concat([df, _ab], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Note that this will work ok for small datasets, but for larger datasets this repeated concatenation is likely to be inefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much, @SultanOrazbayev. The code provided solved my problem. What do you suggest I do for larger datasets? Should I consider rewriting the code altogether? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, depends on the problem. For example, if you are fine leaving the code to run for a while (so your calculations are not time-critical), then it might be OK to leave the code as it is. If not, it might be possible to split calculations into batches (depends on the problem) and run them in parallel... There are many other alternatives.